# asyncio HTTP server hangs up with keepalive

Tags: python, http, network-programming, python-asyncio, keep-alive

I'm trying to write a HTTP/1 server using asyncio, and I'm trying to have it handle HTTP keep-alives. I have the following bit of code.

```
import re
import socket
import asyncio

async def request_handler(reader, writer):
    try:
        keep_alive = True

        while keep_alive:
            keep_alive = False

            while True:
                print('Awaiting data')
                line = await reader.readline()
                print('Finished await got %s' % line)
                if not line.rstrip(b'\r\n'):
                    break

                if re.match(rb'connection:\s*keep-alive', line, re.I):
                    keep_alive = True

            writer.write(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n<h1>My web page</h1>\r\n')
            await writer.drain()
    finally:
        writer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(request_handler, '', 8888, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, loop=loop, limit=2048)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro) 

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()
```

With requests from tools like curl, the request is served correctly without the server hanging up.

However, trying to load the URL in a browser causes the server to never terminate the connection. The browser tries to request two resources, one from `/` and one to `/favicon.ico`, and HTTP keep-alives are used for the requests. (This information can be seen via developer tools.)

I tried printing the data received by the server. However, it seems the server never receives the data for the second request:

```
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Host: localhost:8888\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n'
Awaiting data
Finished await got b'\r\n'
Awaiting data
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Keep-Alive, the response must include the `Content-Length` header (or use the more complex [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) transfer encoding). Without it the client has no choice but to wait for the connection to close - which never happens because `keep_alive` is set to true. For example, if you change the writing code like this:

```
            body = b'<h1>My web page</h1>\r\n'
            writer.write(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n\r\n' % len(body))
            writer.write(body)
```

...the connection is no longer left hanging.

`curl` works because it doesn't specify `Keep-Alive` (because only a single URL was specified on the command line), so your code closes the connection and the content length is not needed.